# OAuth2 invalid_token when verifying Google Sign In with getIdToken() and getServerAuthCode()

Tags: android, google-signin

I followed this guide for Google Sign-In for Android: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

I can successfully sign in but I am not sure if I should be using `getIdToken()` or `getServerAuthCode()` as an access token.

I tried passing both of them, one at a time, to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=[access_token] but it always returns with:

> {  "error": "invalid_token",  "error_description": "Invalid Value" }

Here is what I think are the relevant parts of my code:

```
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    // I also tried String googleAccessToken = acct.getIdToken();
    String googleAccessToken = acct.getServerAuthCode();

    ...

    // Omitted code to make POST request to server
    ...

} else {
    // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
}
```

I've been googling for a few hours but to no avail. Thank you.

EDIT:

Sorry, I think I missed a step. I'm going to try going through this: developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth and give it another shot using GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()

Comment: What do you use the access token for? The ID token is much more secure and performant mechanism for backend auth. And if you need backend access to resources, use the auth code?

Comment: The ID token contains all the info that you are probably using the access token to fetch: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Comment: @StevenSoneff: The backend that my app is using would not accept the ID token. I got it to work with the access token. I checked the code for the backend and it uses https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=[access_token] to validate the token.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to validate the token retrieved with `getIdToken()` you should use the following URL `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123` (notice the difference `?id_token` and `?access_token` you used. You can find find the info about this [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I cannot change the backend code which uses `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=[access_token]` but I will keep that in mind for the future if I ever build my own backend for another project.

Comment: After validating the token is expired, how can we generate a new one?